# Can I display my win/loss stats broken down by race?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am interested in viewing my win/loss ratio broken down by which race my opponent was playing.  I imagine that the opposite would also be nice - to see my win ratio based on who *I* was playing with.  Is there currently a way to find that out?   I poked around but couldn't find one.  Also, is there any way to download my stats as a text file or something and do my own analysis?  I am a chess player, and online chess sites give you all kinds of stats to obsess over, so I'm hoping the same will be true with Bnet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://sc2ranks.com/
make sure you have your character code handy though.

Its not as in-depth as you would probably like to see but it is the best I've seen so far.

Comment: looks promising but I can't find my win ratio by race of opponent.  oh well.

Comment: How do I find out my character code?

Comment: @Carl Clover http://www.l2cheese.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Add-Friend-e1281086863180.jpg 

Source: L2cheese.com

Comment: @Carl Clover you can hover over your portrait in game.

Comment: accepting answer as it is better than nothing, even if it doesn't let me see my ratio by opponent race.